# What did Paul Halmos have in mind in this quotation?

Tags: applications

Paul Halmos says in his paper Innovation in Mathematics in the Scientific american:

> *The late John von Neumann liked to
>   cite this example of the relation between
>   technological  development  and  pure
>   mathematics: A hundred and fifty years
>   ago one of the most important problems
>   of applied science-on which develop­
>   ment in industrv, commerce and gov­ernment depended-was the problem of
>   saving lives at sea. The statistics of the
>   losses were frightful. The money and
>   effort expended to solve the problem
>   were frightful too-and sometimes ludi­crous. No gadget, however complicated,
>   was too ridiculous to consider-ocean­
>   going passenger vessels fitted out like
>   outrigger canoes may have looked funny,
>   but they were worth a try.*
>
> *While leaders
>   of government and industry were des­perately encouraging such crank experiments, mathematicians were developing
>   a tool that was to save more lives than
>   all the crackpot inventors combined
>   dared hope. That tool is what has come
>   to be known as the theory of functions
>   of a complex variable (a variable con­taining the "imaginary" number  $i$,  the square root of minus one). Among the
>   many applications of this purely mathe­matical notion, one of the most fruitful
>   is in the theory of radio communication.
>   From the mathematician Karl Friedrich
>   Gauss to the inventor Guglielmo Mar­coni it is only a few steps that almost
>   any pair of geniuses such as James Clerk
>   Maxwell and Heinrich Hertz can take in
>   their stride.*

I'm asking: what did Halmos have in mind when he stated *"mathematicians were developing
a tool that was to save more lives than
all the crackpot inventors combined
dared hope"*?
That tool is what has come
to be known as the theory of functions
of a complex variable"?
And how?

Comment: Just that complex analysis has many useful applications, including the radio communication used to save lives at sea.

Comment: @anomaly Yes, but I wanted more details.

Comment: Like, how radio communication works, or Maxwell's equations?

Comment: Do you expect any of us to know what Halmos had in his mind? or do you mean "how would we interpret what he said?"  I don't think anyone, except Halmos and God, know what was in his mind when he said that.  So, I think the question as written is impossible to answer.